# How do I change the height of the Android Navigation Bar in the AOSP for Android M?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to change the height of the Navigation Bar. I am making this change in the Android Framework files. I am changing the values I send in to the following method:

```
mTmpNavigationFrame.set(0, top, displayWidth, displayHeight - overscanBottom);
```

Located in:

**frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java**

But it's not increasing the height. After replacing the binaries, it is working differently. The default keys - back, home, recent - are not visible properly.
So how do I increase the height without disturbing the existing buttons in the Navigation Bar?

Do I have to make any changes to **.\SystemUI\src\com\android\systemui\statusbar\phone\NavigationBarView.java** of SystemUI instead? Am I doing the changes in the correct place?

Comment: Its solved now by changing the frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml